# What's the difference between "to herald" and "to announce"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, vocabulary

What's the difference between "to herald" and "to announce"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To herald" can be used to indicate:

- ethusiastic greetings:

> The citizens of York heralded the
>   arrival of the Duke.

- vocal praise:

> The electorate heralded the new
>   anti-immigration policy.

"To announce" can be used to indicate:

- make known:

> The judges announced the rules before starting the contest.

Both verbs can be used interchangeably to indicate:

- foretell:

> The sages had heralded / announced the king's impending defeat at the hands of his enemies.

Although, "to announce" is best avoided in this case.

Comment: WOW!! Crypto, thank You so much for these explanations.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that *herald* is a more formal word than *announce* and isn't used nearly as often. People generally don't use *herald* in casual speech. Even in formal writing, only the meaning of "praise" is really common.